# Which TinyMCE should i download from NuGet?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I am looking to integrate  a WYSIWYG editor to my MVC application. I was considering TinyMCE but there are so many packages on NuGet, i am confused as to which package is right for me.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: what are your requirements?

Comment: Its for small content management so that the user can chose the own fonts, colour, whether to make text bold or not. all such stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a post that explained everything i need and more. If anyone else needs help on how to integrate MVC with TinyMCE read [Tugberk's blogpost](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install the newest package because the newest version of tinymce will be more likely to handle new browsers as they should. The package should be named `TinyMCE 3.5.8` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

I found [WYSIHTML5](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/) to be very flexible and capable.

Comment: Sorry, but i would like to stick with TinyMCE, if not then CKEditor since they have better documentations. Also if its not on NuGet, i am not interested.

Comment: whatever dude. Looks like you already have an opinion. Why ask then? I don't care

Comment: My question is asking for which package of TinyMCE to download from NuGet, i am not sure which to go for since they have so many of them.